# throwing exception in spring cloud stream get a ClassCastException

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am using Spring Cloud Stream 2.0.0 RC3. If I throw an exception in consumer, I will get `ClassCastException`.

I am confused why throwing an exception incurs `ClassCastException`. Is it an expected behavior in Spring Cloud Stream? If a consumer fails to consume message, instead of throwing exception, what is the best practice? (DLQ?)

Code:

```
    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void handle(Person person) throws MessagingException {
        System.out.println("Received: " + person);
        throw new MessagingException(person + " has an error");
    }
```

application.properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=hello
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.error.destination=err
```

Exception:

```
2018-03-28 18:33:34.437 ERROR 7992 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler   : Error while processing: ConsumerRecord(topic = input, partition = 0, offset = 3, CreateTime = 1522233211011, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 23, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = type, value = [34, 112, 101, 114, 115, 111, 110, 95, 110, 97, 109, 101, 95, 101, 114, 114, 111, 114, 34]), RecordHeader(key = contentType, value = [123, 34, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 97, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 34, 44, 34, 115, 117, 98, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 115, 111, 110, 34, 44, 34, 112, 97, 114, 97, 109, 101, 116, 101, 114, 115, 34, 58, 123, 125, 44, 34, 99, 111, 110, 99, 114, 101, 116, 101, 34, 58, 116, 114, 117, 101, 44, 34, 99, 104, 97, 114, 115, 101, 116, 34, 58, 110, 117, 108, 108, 44, 34, 119, 105, 108, 100, 99, 97, 114, 100, 84, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 44, 34, 119, 105, 108, 100, 99, 97, 114, 100, 83, 117, 98, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 102, 97, 108, 115, 101, 125]), RecordHeader(key = spring_json_header_types, value = [123, 34, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 44, 34, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 84, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 117, 116, 105, 108, 46, 77, 105, 109, 101, 84, 121, 112, 101, 34, 125])], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = [B@17b0f35e)

org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler@70b58984]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException cannot be cast to [B
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:177) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:463) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:407) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:164) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:224) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:180) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:463) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:407) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:336) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:227) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:164) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:224) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:180) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:471) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:407) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:98) ~[spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.ErrorMessagePublisher.publish(ErrorMessagePublisher.java:164) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer.recover(ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer.java:83) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted(RetryTemplate.java:512) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:351) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:211) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:40) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1001) [spring-kafka-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:981) [spring-kafka-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:932) [spring-kafka-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:801) [spring-kafka-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:689) [spring-kafka-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException cannot be cast to [B
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.serializeAndEmbedHeadersIfApplicable(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:747) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.0.0.RC3.jar:2.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:724) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.0.0.RC3.jar:2.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:164) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
```

Comment: No, this is not the expected behavior, so I've raised the issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1332. Will follow up.

Comment: I am having problem reproducing it. Do you have any other configuration defined? Error channels, DLQ config etc... ?

Comment: The problem comes from the config:  `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.error.destination=err`. If I remove the config, it will work fine.

Comment: I also tried to use error channel instead of throwing exception:  `errorChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(new MessagingException(person + " has an error")).build());` and got similar result. If I configure custom error channel destination, passing  MessagingException as payload will incur ClassCastException.

Comment: Confirmed, this is a bug. See the above issue for tracking. Will be fixed before 2.0 GA

Comment: The big has been fixed https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1332, Please give it a shot

Comment: FWIW, the bug is fixed, It will go into 2.0 GA, but you can try it now with SNAPSHOTS

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky It works now with SNAPSHOTS. Thanks for your help.